# Why is my grpc so much slower then my minimal api?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

Hey there a bit of an odd question
I've downloaded the code for this :
https://medium.com/geekculture/build-high-performant-microservices-using-grpc-and-net-6-adde158c5ac

Actual Code:
https://github.com/csehammad/gRPCDemoUsingNET6

basically is streams 1 line at a time to a client~---takes about 1 min to stream 1.5 mil lines.

Tried replicating the same behavior with Minimal Api and not sure how,
But it takes 13 seconds to read and stream all 5 million records.

Shouldnt it be slower?
I think my code is badly messed up and probably rotter logic all over the place .

Any Help would be swell
My Ui Code:

```
`using HttpClient client = new();

using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
    "http://localhost:5247/test",
    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead
).ConfigureAwait(false);
IAsyncEnumerable<Sales> Sales= await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IAsyncEnumerable<Sales>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
var count = 0;
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

await foreach (var each in Sales)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("New Order Receieved from {0}-{1},Order ID = {2}, ", each.Country, each.Region, each.TotalRevenue));

}`
```

The Backend:

```
`app.MapGet("/test",  async () =>
{
 return     MakeHttpCall();


});
```

```
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int Count = 0;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path"))
    {
        while (watch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) && !reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var pieces = line.Split(',');
            var _model = new Sales();
          
            _model.Region = pieces[0];
            _model.Country = pieces[1];

            yield return _model;

        }

    }


}`


Also the ui seems to start printing the text only when its all done, meaning not rly streaming..
(removed some code regarding model,watch,and model building --non relevant stuff)


Excpeting it to work after hours of debugging etc but getting nowhere..
```

Comment: Do you have the *actual gRPC client and server code* (in minimal form), so that we can compare and contrast? I suspect you're comparing two very different scenarios here (single payload, albeit streamed, vs multiple payload frames - plus different serialization overheads, but: I'd love to see the details more

Comment: added the repo to the post @MarcGravell

Comment: Benchmark fail.  It takes about a minute on my laptop as well to scroll 1.5 million lines of text on the console.  That doesn't have anything to do with gRPC.

Comment: But as i asid in my version, it takes 13 seconds.